# Получить текст всех нод в TreeView WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, node.js

Мне надо сделать метод, возвращающий массив с текстами всех нод в treeView, включая их всех детей, детей детей и т.д., и исключая ноды с тегом "idea". Как это реализовать?

Comment: может быть добавите немного кода, что пытаетесь сделать, что не получается? Так, возможно, можно будет дать ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<string> allNodesNames = new List<string>(); 
foreach (TreeNode pNode in oYourTreeView.Nodes)
    PrintNodesRecursive(pNode, ref allNodesNames );
```

---

```
public void PrintNodesRecursive(TreeNode oParentNode, ref List<string> allNodesNames)
{
  if ((string)oParentNode.Tag != "Idea")
  {
     allNodesNames.Add(oParentNode.Text);
  }

  // Start recursion on all subnodes.
  foreach(TreeNode oSubNode in oParentNode.Nodes)
  {
    PrintNodesRecursive(oSubNode, ref allNodesNames);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте прочесть [эту статью](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wwc698z7(v=vs.110).aspx) с MSDN, там приведен пример рекурсивного обхода всех узлов TreeView.
Вам нужно доработать код до приемлемого в вашей задаче, либо [вот статья](http://csdeveloper.ru/rekursivnyj-obxod-uzlov-treeview-ili-u-popa-b.html) с примером более подходящим (там свойство Text всех узлов собирается в строковую переменную, а не в массив, и нет проверки тега).

Вот вариант слегка модифицированного кода из последнего примера:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<string> nodesText; //Список для коллекционирования названий нодов
    private string[] Result; //Результирующий массив

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Инициализируем список в конструкторе формы:
        nodesText = new List<string>();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        treeView1.ExpandAll();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode n in treeView1.Nodes)
        {
            WalkTreeNode(n, 0);
        }
        //Преобразуем список в требуемый массив
        Result = nodesText.ToArray();
        //Выводим содержимое именно из массива:
        MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\n", Result));
    }

    private void WalkTreeNode(TreeNode node, Int32 level)
    {
        //Проверяем, есть ли у нас что-то в свойстве Tag, и если есть, не равно ли это значению "Idea", и если это так, то добавляем текст ноды, а теги с "Idea" пропускаем.
        if (!(node.Tag != null && (string)node.Tag == "Idea"))
            {
                nodesText.Add(node.Text);
            }

        foreach (TreeNode n in node.Nodes)
        {
            WalkTreeNode(n, level + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Всё.

Comment: Хороший способ, но мне надо без глобальной переменной

Comment: @Minebot, это поле класса формы, а не глобальная переменная. Но не суть в данном контексте. Да и более компактный и красивый ответ уже [дан](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/574319/222168) )